How to factorize Yocto image recipe
I have three Yocto recipes which build custom system images. They only differ in the WKS_FILE file used for assembling the final image (because they are intended for different usage).

my-sys-base.
my-sys-base-installer.
my-sys-base-standalone.

Recipe file for my-sys-base:
# this file contains all the necessary IMAGE_INSTALL and so on.
require include/my-sys-base.inc

WKS_FILE = "my-sys-base.wks"

Recipe file for my-sys-base-installer:
# this file contains all the necessary IMAGE_INSTALL and so on.
require include/my-sys-base.inc

WKS_FILE = "my-sys-base-installer.wks"

Recipe file for my-sys-base-standalone:
# this file contains all the necessary IMAGE_INSTALL and so on.
require include/my-sys-base.inc

WKS_FILE = "my-sys-base-standalone.wks"

Currently, when I build the three recipes, Yocto creates three dedicated rootfs directories (and all other stuffs). This takes some time to complete and increases disk space in use.
I tried gathering everything under one single recipe without success. Bitbake tells "Nothing PROVIDES 'my-sys-base-standalone'":
require include/my-sys-base.inc

WKS_FILE = "my-sys-base.wks"
WKS_FILE:${PN}-installer = "my-sys-base-installer.wks"
WKS_FILE:${PN}-standalone = "my-sys-base-standalone.wks"

QUESTION: How can I make the recipes my-sys-base-installer and my-sys-base-standalone be based on my-sys-base?
My target goal is to build them relying on my-sys-base files so that if my-sys-base is up to date then only the image assembly with wic gets executed.
